# Sorcery User Factory Not Valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, sorcery

I am trying to get into writing better tests with rspec and factory girl. I am trying to test my user model, but my first test keeps failing. I use Sorcery for my authentication system, but I can't find too many examples of how to write the factory. I got a clue from an issue on the sorcery github repo, but the test is still failing.

Here is my User factory:

```
# spec/factories/users.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  salt = "asdasdastr4325234324sdfds"
  factory :user do
     sequence(:username)   { |n| "testuser#{n}" }
     slug              :username
     email                 { "#{username}@example.com" }
     password              "secret"
     password_confirmation "secret"
     salt                  salt
     crypted_password      Sorcery::CryptoProviders::BCrypt.encrypt("secret", salt)
     admin                 false
   end
 end
```

This is the model test:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
   it "has a valid factory" do
     FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
   end
end
```

Here's the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  # Use FriendlyId for better URLs
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, :use => :slugged
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :weburl, :time_zone, :bio

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on =>:create
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
1) User has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
  expected valid? to return true, got false
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 6 of user_spec.rb is `FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid`

I'm sure I'm missing something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you include your user model code, and specifically the validation part?

Comment: I edited my question to include the user model.

Answer (score 0):

The factory says that the User is invalid. To figure out why, check the errors.

```
user = Factory.build(:user)
user.valid? # => false
user.errors.should be_empty # => fails, and prints the error hash
```